# Can I leave feedback for classified item on eBay?

Tags: ebay

I want to leave feedback for an item I bought on eBay that was listed as a classified, but I can't even find the item in My eBay.

Is it not possible to leave feedback for classifieds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.
From the [Different ways of buying](http://pages.ebay.com/help/buy/formats.html#classified) help article:

> When you see a Classified Ad listing, it means that you deal directly with the seller and buy the item at a fixed price. Because your Classified Ad purchase is outside of eBay, you won't be able to use eBay Feedback or eBay Buyer Protection.

Comment: Okay, thanks for locating that. I think they should remove the reputation count from the listing since this is the case.